# Javascript onclick function pass img src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 images which each have an `onclick` and a parameter passed. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="myfunction(1);">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider1.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="myfunction(2);">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider2.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="myfunction(3);">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider3.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need to do is have a function which gets the `img` `src` value of the `myfunction` passed parameter. So for example:

```
myFunction(id) {
    $('body').html(/* passed parameter's img src here */);    
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to pass the img src as body background?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass `this` as a parameter to the function which will be a reference to the clicked `div` element. You can then get the child `img` and read the `src` attribute.

However a much better solution would be to use unobtrusive event handlers over outdated `on*` event attributes. Try this:

```js
$('.thumbnail').click(function() {
  var $thumb = $(this);
  console.log($thumb.data('foo'));
  console.log($thumb.find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" data-foo="1">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider1.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" data-foo="2">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider2.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" data-foo="3">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider3.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Onlcick of respective divs image src can be get using `var imgSrc = "assets/placeholders/sliders/slider" + id + ".png";` and it can be used as per need.

Please check working snippet.

```js
function myfunction(id) {
  //Get image src on click on the respective divs
  var imgSrc = "assets/placeholders/sliders/slider" + id + ".png";
  console.log(imgSrc);
  //$('body').html( passed parameter's img src here );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="myfunction(1);"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider1.png" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="myfunction(2);"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider2.png" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="myfunction(3);"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider3.png" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an id attribute to your `img` tags and give them your id parameter.

```
<img id="1" ... />
<img id="2" ... />
<img id="3" ... />
```

In your script you can fetch them with jQuery.

```
myFunction(id) {

  var src = $('#' + id).attr('src');
  $('body').html(src);

}
```

However, there multiple ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Using `onclick` attribute you can pass `this` keyword in `myfunction` which represents the current element, and then look for the `src` attribute.

```js
function myfunction(e){
var src = $(e).find('img').attr('src');
alert(src);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="myfunction(this);"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider1.png" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="myfunction(this);"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider2.png" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="myfunction(this);"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider3.png" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Even though you can achieve the desired outcome, this way of using `onclick` attributes for Javascript is not a good practice. Javascript developers recommend you should always put javascript entirely in a separate file.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.thumbnail').on('click', function(){
var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
alert(src);  
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" ><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider1.png" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" ><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider2.png" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail" ><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/placeholders/sliders/slider3.png" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```